# Syntactic tree with tikz-qtree and annotations and labels over multiple lines

Tags: trees, tikz-qtree

I am going mad trying to draw syntactic trees using the tikz-qtree package. Here is what I have come up with:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center},level distance=1.5cm]
\Tree [.S 
          [.{NP\\($\uparrow$~{\sc subj})~=~$\downarrow$}
              [.{N\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
                  [. John 
                  ] 
              ]
          ]
          [.{VP\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
              [.V
                  [.{saw\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}]
                  ]
              [.{NP\\($\uparrow$~{\sc obj})~=~$\downarrow$}
                  [.{DET\\($\uparrow$~{\sc def})~=~+}
                  ]
                  [.{N\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
                      [. boy 
                      ]
                  ]
              ]
          ]
      ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
```

However, tex keeps complaining about a runaway argument, and I can't seem to be able to spot what I'm doing wrong. It seems to me that I need to use curly braces because the labels on the tree span multiple lines. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post complete code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've run into a pretty common error for users of `qtree`/`tikz-qtree`: the package syntax requires that all closing brackets must be preceded by whitespace. If you add a space (or a line break, as [Jesse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222118/42880) does) before the bracket that closes the *saw* node, your MWE compiles without errors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center},level distance=1.5cm]
    \Tree [.S 
    [.{NP\\($\uparrow$~{\sc subj})~=~$\downarrow$}
    [.{N\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
    [. John 
    ] 
    ]
    ]
    [.{VP\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
    [.V
    [.{saw\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$} ] % the space before the closing bracket is crucial
    ]
    [.{NP\\($\uparrow$~{\sc obj})~=~$\downarrow$}
    [.{DET\\($\uparrow$~{\sc def})~=~+}
    ]
    [.{N\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
    [. boy 
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### EDIT

Below I've made some additional improvements to your code:

- Changed the deprecated `\sc` to `\textsc{}` as suggested by cfr
- Changed `every node` to `every tree node` and added `anchor=north` so that the top of the V node is vertically aligned with the top of the NP node
- Limited the level distance increase to the 2nd level and lower so that there isn't too much vertical space between the S and its daughters

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north},level 2+/.style={level distance=1.5cm}] % changed "every node" to "every tree node" and added "anchor=north" so that the top of the V node is vertically aligned with the top of the NP node; increased the level distance for only the 2nd level and lower
    \Tree [.S 
    [.{NP\\($\uparrow$~\textsc{subj})~=~$\downarrow$} % changed \sc to \textsc{}
    [.{N\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
    [. John 
    ] 
    ]
    ]
    [.{VP\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
    [.V
    [.{saw\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$} ]
    ]
    [.{NP\\($\uparrow$~\textsc{obj})~=~$\downarrow$} % changed \sc to \textsc{}
    [.{DET\\($\uparrow$~\textsc{def})~=~+} % changed \sc to \textsc{}
    ]
    [.{N\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
    [. boy 
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\sc` was deprecated 20+ years ago. It is from LaTeX 2.09. The 2e commands are `\scshape` or `\textsc{}`.

Comment: @cfr, yes, good point. Sorry I missed that in the MWE.

Comment: (+1) Easy to miss. Good explanation of Jesse's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result after debugging. The errors found are indicated by <---.

Edit: There are two ways of doing this. The new one is on the top while the old one follows.  The new one is found after the two brackets are put together.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}

new solution

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center},level distance=1.5cm]
\Tree [.S 
          [.{NP\\($\uparrow$~{\scshape subj})~=~$\downarrow$}
              [.{\strut N\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
                  [. John 
                  ] 
              ]
          ]
          [.{VP\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}  
              [.V
                  [.{ saw\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
                  ]] % <---  this is how it work, 
              [.{NP\\($\uparrow$~{\scshape obj})~=~$\downarrow$} 
                  [.{DET\\($\uparrow$~{\scshape def})~=~+}
                  ]
                  [.{N\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
                      [. boy 
                      ]
                  ]
              ]
          ]
        ]
\end{tikzpicture}

% Old solution
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center},level distance=1.5cm]
\Tree [.S 
          [.{NP\\($\uparrow$~{\scshape subj})~=~$\downarrow$}
              [.{N\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
                  [. John 
                  ] 
              ]
          ]
          [.{VP\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}  
              [.V
                  [.{saw\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$} % <---
                  ]
              [.{NP\\($\uparrow$~{\scshape obj})~=~$\downarrow$} 
                  [.{DET\\($\uparrow$~{\scshape def})~=~+}
                  ]
                  [.{N\\$\uparrow$~=~$\downarrow$}
                      [. boy 
                      ]
                  ]
               ]
               ]
          ]
       ]   %<---
\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{test}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!! But now I'm confused as to why this works. It seems to me that the square brackets are not balanced - there is one more closing bracket in the end than there are opening brackets. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: OK, you have two brackets at the end of verb `saw` where only one is required to close the branch. And the last bracket at the end is to close the entire sentence (S). Without the last bracket, only the verb phrase (VP) is closed which will still cause error. All the brackets are balanced. You have two branches. It is fairly clear from the structure there are NP and VP.

Comment: `\sc` is deprecated.

Comment: I hope you don't mind - I updated the commands because I wanted to (+1) the answer. Especially for disambiguating the readings. Not sure you need `graphicx`?

Comment: Thanks. @cfr, No need for graphicx. I copy and paste preamble from elsewhere when worked on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `forest` version which makes use of a couple of new commands to make coding the tree a bit simpler. (You could use these with the `tikz-qtree` solutions instead, of course.)

```
\upit{arg}
```

takes one mandatory argument, `arg`. It typesets an upwards arrow followed by `arg` in small caps, all wrapped in parentheses.

```
\updown{arg}
```

takes an optional argument, `arg`, but lets you use `{}` rather than `[]` so you don't have to wrap everything in curly brackets to avoid having the argument read as a new node. If no argument is specified, it typesets an upwards arrow, an equals sign and a downwards arrow. Otherwise, it typesets the `arg` as `\upit` does, adds an equals sign and finishes with a downwards arrow.

I include the code for the basic tree:

[image: tree 1]

and a variant which seems to be quite common:

[image: tree 2]

The only difference in code is the addition of

```
if n children=0{tier=terminal}{},
```

to the tree configuration in the second case.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, varwidth, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest, mathtools, xparse}
\standaloneenv{forest}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand*\upit[1]{\ensuremath{(\uparrow\,\text{\scshape #1})}}
  \NewDocumentCommand\updown { g }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
      \ensuremath{\uparrow\,=\,\downarrow}%
    }{%
      \ensuremath{(\uparrow\,\text{\scshape #1})\,=\,\downarrow}%
    }}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center,
      base=top,
    }
    [S
      [NP\\\updown{subj}
        [N\\\updown
          [John
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [VP\\\updown
        [V
          [saw\\\updown
          ]
        ]
        [NP\\\updown{obj}
          [DET\\{$\upit{def} = +$}
            [the
            ]
          ]
          [N\\\updown
            [boy
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center,
      base=top,
      if n children=0{tier=terminal}{},
    }
    [S
      [NP\\\updown{subj}
        [N\\\updown
          [John
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [VP\\\updown
        [V
          [saw\\\updown
          ]
        ]
        [NP\\\updown{obj}
          [DET\\{$\upit{def} = +$}
            [the
            ]
          ]
          [N\\\updown
            [boy
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```